# Segment Image of Small Elements on Neutral Background

Tags: image-processing, image-segmentation, edge-detection, image-analysis, connected-components

[image]

I have a 8 bit gray level image where if the value = 122 it means no information, value = 0 means highly negative, and value = 255 means highly positive.
I want to connect as many positive information pixels with each other as possible to form as large an area as possible (and not let accidental negative values affect it), and get all the contour of it (which I will then filter out based on # of positive dots and total area of the contour). The ideal contours are the red lines I have drawn onto the image above, and the full image is below.

[image]

What is the best strategy to go about doing this?

The 3rd image is a zoomed in view of the image to show the pixels after filtering / processing just looks like that.

[[image][3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vnUP9.png)

Comment: have you got actual data or just this resampled image? people are going to need something to experiment with, if you don't just want random ideas. -- something based on a median might serve the purpose. I don't mean *just* applying a median kernel.

Comment: The 2nd png image is the actual data. I normalized the values to 0 - 255, with 0 being definitely negative, 255 being definitely positive, and the middle level being no information.

Comment: those pixels look resampled/resized. is this a screenshot? that picture definitely doesn't just contain three levels (black, white, single middle level)

Comment: Nope this is indeed the actual image, here's a zoomed in view of the actual pixels

Comment: how is this image made? is resizing/resampling happening at any place in the previous processing?

Comment: Hi Christoph, I edited the original question to include the zoomed in pic. I just resize the image with interpolation set to nearest so you can see each blocks of pixel.
The picture does not contain just 3 levels, ranges from 0 - 255, 0 being definitely negative, 255 being definitely positive, and 127 being "no opinion". I want to find contours of regions of positives (even if it occasionally have some "possibly negative" noises)

Comment: this might be doable with some morphology operations (erode/dilate/median). this might require more complex operations. I'm afraid that you _could_ provide better data, which would make this easier, but don't for some reason. it's other people's time, free of charge. every time I spend the effort and later learn that OP could have made my life 10x easier, with data and/or explanations (you still didn't say how the original picture happened; it's surely not "the word of god"), it is frustrating.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The idea I have is as following:

1. Treat data as a density measure.
2. Values > 122, positive density, Values < 122 negative.
3. Cluster them by threshold.

This is how it goes:

1. Scale image into `[0, 1]` range.
2. Shift the values by `122 / 255` so zero value are zero.
3. Convolve with Gaussian Kernel.
4. Apply threshold.
5. Clean small artifacts.
6. Do connected components.
7. Draw contour of connected components.

I will show steps 1-4.

- The input image

[image]

- The surface after convolution (Hills and valleys)

[image]

- Image after thresholding (Basically which have the same baseline of density)

[image]

What I'd do next to finish this:

1. Tweak parameters.
2. Clean small artifacts using morphological operations.
3. Draw the contours bases on the connected components.

The MATLAB code:

```matlab
clear();
close('all');

zeroLvl = 122 / 255;
thrLvl = 0.01;

mI = imread('https://i.stack.imgur.com/QMTb5.png');
mI = mI(:, :, 1);
mI = im2double(mI);

figure();
imshow(mI);

mK = fspecial('gaussian', [25, 25], 4.5);

mB = mI - zeroLvl;
mP = imfilter(mB, mK, 'replicate');

figure();
surf(mP, 'EdgeColor', 'none');

mT = mP > thrLvl;

figure();
imshow(mT);

sCC = bwconncomp(mT);
figure();
contour(mP);
```